# display custom post type in widget aera

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets

I am using https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ plugin for custom post types. Now I need to display contact information in my footer area, email, phone num , address etc. For this I have created custom post type using above plugin named `contact`, now how should I display this post type in my widget area so I can display all of its fields in my footer.php.

Comment: Have you tried these [examples from the codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Querying_by_Post_Type). For custom fields you could use [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to make a post type Contact.Just make a dynamic sidebar in the Widget area of Wordpress.And take the Text Widget in that Dynamic Sidebar , Copy your html and Paste it there in the Dynamic Widget Area you make. If you are not able to make the Dynamc sidebar Paste ths code in you functon.php

```
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'contact_sidebar', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-4',
    'description'   => __( 'Appears on posts and pages in the sidebar.', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '<h2>',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
```

Then call it on your footer.php by

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-4');?>
```